# Why does reduce return the number itself and, as in functional programming, replace if and break?

Tags: javascript

There is a simple function, its essence is to count from a number (n) to 0.
But when using reduce, the function just doesn't work, and no matter how I rewrite it, it returns either an empty array, or undefined, or the number itself 2.
First, I created an array that will take n, then I created a reduce method in which currentValue will take n and subtract 1 from it, after accumulator it takes the resulting number and using the push method, add it to the list array, but I don’t understand how I should add a condition that if accumulator is equal to 0, then the function must be stopped.

```js
const countBits = (n) => {
    let list = [n];
    let resultReduce = n.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
            accumulator = currentValue - 1;
            list.push(accumulator);
        }); 
    return resultReduce;
};
console.log(countBits([2]));
```

Why isn't this working the way I intended it to?

Comment: Have you seen the documentation for the [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method? The value for the accumulator argument gets set based on what you `return` from your callback on its previous call. Some of the examples from the docs might clear it up a little

Comment: @NickParsons As I understand it, you are talking about initialValue? As I understand it, in the absence of initialValue, should accumulator automatically take on the value 0?

Comment: @DAS I'm mainly talking about `return`ing from your callback, which you are not doing. But yes, the initial value for the accumulator does also matter. In your case if it is not supplied it will be first value of the array you're using `.reduce()` on, in that case it will be `n` (which you're passing into your function as `[2]`). See Jack's answer for a better option for solving this, as reduce isn't the right tool here

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks for the answer, but I want to understand something else. If the result of the previous callback = 1, will accumulator be 1 as well?

Comment: @DAS depends on what you mean by "the result of the previous callback = 1", but if the callback were to `return 1`, then the next time it is the callback is called for the next item in the array the accumulator will be `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reduce` will run on each of the items in the array, with the `accumulator` (first argument to the callback function) being the value that is returned from the callback function's previous iteration. So if you don't return anything, `accumulator` will be `undefined` for the next iteration.

If you want to count from `n` to `0`, `reduce` is not the way to go (as well as the fact that in your current implementation, you don't even use `list` which would contain all of your stored numbers from `n` to `0`). I would advise that instead, you simply loop from `n` to `0` and push those values into an array like so:

```js
const countBits = (n) => {
    let list = [];
    for (let i = n; i > -1; i--) {
      list.push(i);
    }
    return list;
};
console.log(countBits(2));
```

Also note I've changed your syntax slightly in the function call - you were passing an array with a single element seemingly unnecessarily, so I just passed the element itself to simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Jack Bashford is correct, but for completeness I would like to point out that generating a range of numbers is a common need. Libraries like [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#range), [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#range) and [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#range) provide a ready-to-use function for this purpose. You don’t have to write your own implementation every time you need something common and mundane like that; save the time and enjoy the fact that you can spend your time on something more groundbreaking instead.

```js
console.log(_.range(2, -1, -1));
```

```html
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

Also for the sake of completeness, let’s consider how you *might* implement a downwards `range` function using `reduce`, anyway. `reduce` expects an input array, though it can also accept an object if using Underscore or Lodash. To make meaningful use of the input collection, we could generate a consecutive number for every element of the collection. For an array, we could of course just do `_.range(collection.length - 1, -1, -1)` instead, but for an object, or something that you don’t know the length of in advance, such as a generator, using `reduce` for this purpose might make sense. The `mapDownwardsRange` function below will do this:

```js
function unshiftNext(array) {
    const front = array.length ? array[0] : -1;
    return [front + 1].concat(array);
}

function mapDownwardsRange(collection) {
    return _.reduce(collection, unshiftNext, []);
}

console.log(mapDownwardsRange(['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

```html
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```